# Работа с веб камерой С++

Tags: web-camera, c++

Пытаюсь научиться программно научиться снимать изображение с веб камеры и обрабатывать его. В процессе копания в интернете наткнулся на vfw.h, но вот описание не нашёл. Помогите, пожалуйста!

Comment: Что за vfw.h??! если хочшеь работать с камерой, поставь OpenCV и не мучайся :)

Answer (score 3):

Согласно [википедии](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_for_Windows), последний выпуск датирован 96 годом и предназначен для Windows NT. Нет никакого смысла использовать настолько устаревший продукт. Наследником Video for Windows является [DirectShow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd375454%28VS.85%29.aspx), его и используйте.